# shell script to validate eclipse code formatter xml

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I am planning to write a pre commit hook in svn for validating the code formatting before checkin to the svn repo. I am using eclipse as my IDE and have set up custom code formatting rules and all of my team members are using the xml to format the java code.

However, I need to validate in the pre-commit of svn that the checkin meets the code format that is being defined. The eclipse code formatter exports the formatting rules in an xml. In the pre-commit hook I am planning to write a shell script which should validate the file to be checked in against the code format xml.

Could you please let me know how to get this implemented.

Regards,
Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

It's not specifically a pre-commit hook, but this is what I've started using:

http://code.google.com/p/maven-java-formatter-plugin/

You could wrap the format task as a pre-commit hook I'd imagine.  I use it to format every time I do a "mvn package" (follow their examples on how to do this).  You'll be able to use the same Eclipse formatting rules that you've been using.  It's pretty darned slick.